# Populating a table with Angular using angular-datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am new to Angular and angular-datatables. This is a pretty general question. I see that you can populate a table easily with a JSON file like so:

```
var vm = this;
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
```

I however, have my row data as an array of Objects, each object being a row on the table. I am wondering if JSON is the only way to populate the table. I cannot seem to populate my table with my array of Objects.

Comment: Just to be clearer, it seems like the JSON implementation is static, meaning the data you want on the table comes from that file and doesn't change. I have a server with these table rows and when I pull from it I get my data as this array of objects, which I need to use to populate the table.

Comment: make a json object out of your array